# Getting reviews of newly associated place with Google Business

Tags: google-places-api, google-my-business-api

We have a platform in which we are integrating Google Business API and before that we were just using Google Places API.

We kinda have similar scenario like the one below

https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-My-Business-API/Google-Places-API-and-My-Business-API/td-p/575081

I have followed the instruction of first answer by "Terry".

I have done following steps

- Used OAuth 2.0 for authentication and authorization
- Created a new, unverified location
- Found all of the possible locations that are a match to the unverified location
- Upon the user’s selection and approval, associated the unverified location to a specified place ID
- I am getting the reviews of approved/published business locations.

Here's the issue:

I want to get the reviews of that newly associated business location.

How can i achieve that?

Second question is, is it possible to associate a place Id with businesses location which is not returned by Google Business API Find Matches endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally this is what i get from GMB team.

"In the Google My Business API, the review operation is only valid if the specified location is verified, the only boolean field of the "[LocationState object](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v3/accounts.locations#LocationState)" in a location you should check for is "[isVerified](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v3/accounts.locations#LocationState.FIELDS.is_verified)".

Ref: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-My-Business-API/Google-Places-API-and-My-Business-API/m-p/1605702#M7933